# Bus error 10 in Radix Tree C program

Tags: c, trie, radix

I'm writing a program which does operations on a Radix trie and I'm stuck at add() function, getting the Bus error 10.

```
void addRec(struct tNode *p, char *w) {

  int matches = prefixMatch(p->word,w);

  bool insert = true;

  if ((p == root) || 
  ((matches > 0) && (matches < strlen(w)) && (matches == strlen(p->word)))) {


    char *updatedWord = &w[matches];    
    printf("%s\n", updatedWord);

    struct tNode *tmp = p->child;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
      if (tmp->word[0] == updatedWord[0]) {
        insert = false;
        addRec(tmp, updatedWord);
      }
      tmp = tmp->brother;
    }
    if (insert) {
      addChild(p,updatedWord);
    } 
    } else if ((matches > 0) && (matches == strlen(w)) && (matches == strlen(p->word))) {
    if (p->count < 0) p->count = ++globalCount;
    else printf("ignored");
    } else if ((matches > 0) && (matches < strlen(w)) && (matches < strlen(p->word))) {
    struct tNode *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct tNode));
    tmp->word = &p->word[matches];
    p->word[matches+1] = '\0';
    tmp->child = p->child;
    tmp->count = p->count;
    tmp->brother = NULL;
    p->child = tmp;
    p->count = -1;

  } 


}
```

The error appears to be somewhere inside the while loop but I can't figure out where and what's wrong exactly. Please help.

Comment: Did you run in a debugger to maybe narrow it down even further? Like what line the crash happens on?

Comment: No I didn't. I tried some step by step debugging by outputting some messages in different places, but still it was unclear to me what's wrong. All I know is that when I access p->child's attributes, everything's fine, but when I try to put it in the loop this wierd bus error occurs

Comment: So try. At the very least the debugger will tell you what line the error is occuring on. And if you want people to help it would be good to format your code properly and add a few comments (both of which are essential good practice anyway).

Comment: The error appears to be in the line 
struct tNode *tmp = p->child;

I still don't know what's wrong though

Comment: Are you sure `w` should be a pointer-to-char, not pointer-to-pointer-to-char?